# A positive sequence must monotonically converges for large enough index.

Tags: sequences-and-series

This question is rather simple,

Let $a_n$ be a sequence that converges to zero, exists a $N$ such that for all $n>N$ the following $a_{n+1}\le a_{n}$

Is the theorem above correct? I am confused since I used it in an exam and the professor said that this does not necessarily happen, looking for a counter-example or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is *false*.  From the question title, it's better to give a simple example using a sequence with *positive* entries.  Counterexample:

Consider the sequence $(a_n)$

$$2,\frac12,\dots,\frac{2}{2n-1},\frac{1}{2n},\dots$$

Since each term $a_n$ has a denominator which tends to infinity as $n\to+\infty$, $a_n\to0$ as $n\to+\infty$.

$$a_{2n-1}-a_{2n} = \frac{2}{2n-1}-\frac1{2n}=\frac{2n+1}{2n(2n-1)}>0 \text{, but}$$
$$a_{2n}-a_{2n+1} = \frac1{2n}-\frac{2}{2n+1}=\frac{-2n+1}{2n(2n+1)}<0$$

Therefore, the sequence $(a_n)$ converges to zero while *fluctuating*.

Answer (score 9):

The claim is incorrect.

Consider the sequence $a_k = \frac{2 + (-1)^k}{k}$.  This sequence is positive as requested in the title and converges to zero but contradicts the conclusion of the claim.

Comment: The body doesn't repeat it, but the title seems to ask for a *positive* sequence.

Comment: @ClementC. I guess those who upvoted it can complete the argument from this sequence.  Btw, I +1'ed b4 knowing how.

Comment: @ClementC Thanks for pointing that out.  I missed that in the title.  I've changed it to a slightly different sequence that is positive.

Answer (score 6):

It's false, as can be seen by this counter-example
$$a_n=\frac1n+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^2}.$$
This sequence has positive terms but is not monotonically convergent to $0$. One checks $a_{2p}>a_{2p+1}$ and $a_{2p+1}<a_{2p+2}$.

Comment: It's easily fixable while keeping the spirit, but  the OP asks for a sequence going to 0.

Comment: @Clement C. : I thought  the O.P. wanted a series with positive terms. I probably misread. I 'll add an example converging to $0$.

Comment: OP also included positive in the title description.

Comment: OK, I eventually got it – and got a counter-example satisfying all constraints, if my computations are correct.

Answer (score 6):

This claim is not true.

**Hint**: consider the sequence defined by $x_{2n}=2^{-n}$ and $x_{2n+1}=3^{-n}$.

Answer (score 3):

A more generic method to construct such a sequence: Take an arbitrary convergent sequence that *strictly* monotonic decreases, that is, $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for all $n$. Then you can construct a new sequence $b_n$ by $b_{2n}=a_{2n+1}$, $b_{2n+1}=a_{2n}$. It is not hard to check that $b_n$ converges to the same limit as $a_n$, but never gets monotonic as by construction $b_{2n+1}>b_{2n}$.

Also note that from each monotonic decreasing convergent sequence that doesn't eventually get constant, you can get a strictly monotonic decreasing one with the same limit by simply omitting the repetitions.

Also note that when considering the discrete topology (e.g. by considering integer sequences only), your assumption *is* true, as there only the sequences that eventually get constant are convergent, and the constant sequence is monotonic decreasing.

Comment: Please fix $b_{2n+1} = a_{2n}$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: Fixed, thank you. I just spotted that I also had an actual math error, too, which I now also fixed.